# htmlでテキスト表示する際、(画面幅等により、)折り返しが発生するかどうかを事前に判定する方法はありますか？

Tags: javascript

**下記のようなdivに任意のテキストを表示する際、(画面幅等により、)折り返しが発生するかどうかを事前に判定する方法はありますか？**
対象divの横幅は指定しない。左右のmarginのみ指定

```
<div style="margin:0:15px;">ここに長さが異なるテキストを表示する<div>
```

Comment: 「事前」とは、どのタイミングを指していますか？

Comment: ブラウザが読み込むタイミングで「折り返しありなし」判定ができれば、対象要素にclass等を付与することで「改行ありのレイアウト」と「改行なしのレイアウト」を切り替えられるのではないか、と思い質問しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

インラン要素やテキストノードに `getClientRects` を使うと一行ごとのDOMRectが得られます。
折り返しがある場合には戻り値が2つ以上になるのでそれで判断できます。

```js
function hasLineBreak(textNode) {
  let range = new Range()
  range.selectNode(textNode)
  return range.getClientRects().length > 1
}

document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(el => {
  let ret = hasLineBreak(el.firstChild)
  console.log(ret, el.firstChild.textContent)
})
```

```html
<div style="margin:0:15px;">ここに長さが異なるテキストを表示する</div>

<br>

<div style="margin:0:15px;">ここに長さが異なるテキストを表示するここに長さが異なるテキストを表示するここに長さが異なるテキストを表示するここに長さが異なるテキストを表示するここに長さが異なるテキストを表示するここに長さが異なるテキストを表示するここに長さが異なるテキストを表示するここに長さが異なるテキストを表示する</div>
```

```html
<div style="margin:0:15px;">ここに長さが異なるテキストを表示する</div>

<br>

<div style="margin:0:15px;">ここに長さが異なるテキストを表示するここに長さが異なるテキストを表示するここに長さが異なるテキストを表示するここに長さが異なるテキストを表示するここに長さが異なるテキストを表示するここに長さが異なるテキストを表示するここに長さが異なるテキストを表示するここに長さが異なるテキストを表示する</div>
```

```js
function hasLineBreak(textNode) {
  let range = new Range()
  range.selectNode(textNode)
  return range.getClientRects().length > 1
}

document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(el => {
  let ret = hasLineBreak(el.firstChild)
  console.log(ret, el.firstChild.textContent)
})
```

今回はテキストノードをel.firstChildで取得しましたが、実際にはidつきのspanで囲むと良いと思います。

Comment: 期待通り動作しました。また、回答を読んで「Range インターフェイス」というものがあることを初めて知りました。大変参考になりました